# How to stop execution for function with Userscript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

The Website I want to write an Userscript for has something like that:

```
p.Stream = p.Class.extend({
         .
         .
         .
_processResponse: function(data) {
    if (!data.items || !data.items.length) {
        return null;
    }
    this.reached.start = data.atStart || this.reached.start;
    this.reached.end = data.atEnd || this.reached.end;
    var oldestId, newestId;
    if (this.options.promoted) {
        data.items.sort(p.Stream.sortByPromoted);
        oldestId = data.items[data.items.length - 1].promoted;
        newestId = data.items[0].promoted;
    } else {
        data.items.sort(p.Stream.sortById);
        oldestId = data.items[data.items.length - 1].id;
        newestId = data.items[0].id;
    }
    var position = (oldestId < this._oldestId) ? p.Stream.POSITION.APPEND : p.Stream.POSITION.PREPEND;
    this._oldestId = Math.min(this._oldestId, oldestId);
    this._newestId = Math.max(this._newestId, newestId);
    var prev = null;
    var itemVotes = p.user.voteCache.votes.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        var item = data.items[i];
        item.thumb = CONFIG.PATH.THUMBS + item.thumb;
        item.image = CONFIG.PATH.IMAGES + item.id;

        item.fullsize = item.fullsize ? CONFIG.PATH.FULLSIZE + item.fullsize : null;
        item.vote = itemVotes[item.id] || 0;
        this.items[item.id] = item;
    }
    return position;
}
});
```

I want to manipulate the `_processResponse` such that `item.image` points to another Source. Is this possible with Userscripts? I tried overriding the function like stated on some websites but that does not work like expected. I just want to override this function, nothing other than that.

Comment: we don't have the notion of overriding functions in javascript. you can place a conditional statement that suits your need. less code. more productivity.

Comment: @RaminOmrani Could you give me an example on how I can accomplish this with an Userscript?

Comment: I don't know userscript language. but if its the same as javascript its as simple as using an `if` statement

Comment: @RaminOmrani OK I am sorry but I think you don't understand my question, the code block in my question is provided on the Website's JavaScript code, the userscript will be installed on the client side and must override the function in order to work as I want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the easiest and most flexible way to do that would be to wrap `_processResponse` in a function that further operates on `data` after the original function is called:

```
var oldfunc = p.Stream.prototype._processResponse;
p.Stream.prototype._processResponse = function(data) {
    var ret = oldfunc.apply(this, arguments);
    if(data.items && data.items.length)
    {
        for(var i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; ++i)
        {
            data.items[i].image = 'https://example.com/a.png'; // or whatever
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but what should `arguments` be in `oldfunc.apply(this, arguments)`

Comment: @Ybrin https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments It's just a thing in JavaScript.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood something, but I have now exactly what you have posted in my Script, and I put an alert as a debug message inside `function(data) {}` but it never gets executed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ybrin Nope, my bad. `p` should have been `p.Stream.prototype`.

Comment: Ok now it gets executed but ends up with this error in the debug console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined`, but the original javascript has never got this problem so it seems like this piece of code gets executed too early or so...

Comment: And you're telling me that error occurs within an `if(data.items){...}` clause? Are you sure you didn't accidentally remove any `data.` before `items`?

Comment: Yes, just try it yourself, the site where I want to use the script is http://pr0gramm.com

Comment: Works for me in both Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey... I just add a new script, paste my code, add `// @include /^https?:\/\/pr0gramm\.com/.*$/` and it works as I'd expect.